# SF short story (Arthur C. Clarke?) about an astronaut's realisation that Leonardo da Vinci got to the Moon?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to identify a short story written, I think, by Arthur C. Clarke in the 1940s/50s.

A lunar astronaut finds a strange rock formation which reminds him of something. He also finds footprints. Back on Earth, he visits the National Gallery in London's Trafalgar Square and sees Leonardo da Vinci's painting, "The Virgin of the Rocks". He recognises the rocks in the painting as the ones he's seen on the Moon. Ergo, Leonardo got there first!

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 27):

It's actually Poul Anderson's "[The Light](http://poulandersonappreciation.blogspot.com/2014/03/the-light.html)" ([ISFDB](http://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45952)).

> Anderson's "The Man Who Came Early" is a first person narration addressed to a single auditor, a priest. "The Light" is another first person narration addressed to a single auditor, this time a historian who is being told government secrets - and the surprise ending of the story reveals why. Someone reached the Moon before the Americans. (The background of da Vinci's The Virgin of the Rocks does look as if it might be a Lunar landscape, doesn't it?)

A search for `science fiction astronaut "leonardo da vinci" moon clarke` brought me to [this list](http://www.launchdate.com/moon/moonscifi.htm) where a text search for "da vinci" found me the mention of "The Light" whereupon I did a search for that and Poul Anderson's name to get the blog entry about it.

Comment: Fuzz, I think the incidental claim in the quote ("The background of da Vinci's The Virgin of the Rocks does look as if it might be a Lunar landscape") is pretty bizarre!  it really looks in no way at all lunar!

Comment: @Fattie: I am agreed.

Comment: For what it's worth, the story was first published in 1957, so the actual appearance of lunar rocks was less clear at the time.